# Mouse Click Operation VC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

```
if (i==0)
{
 //Here I've to do MouseDown operation
}
else
{
 //perform MouseUp operation
}
```

This is sample code i wann do somethin' like above...

i can move the mouse by SetCursorPos(). So how can i perform click events

Comment: Why is it tagged with `opencv` ? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm Doing something like Virtual mouse using Opencv library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any form of input can be simulated using the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function (there is also the deprecated [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function as well, which I find easier to use, but is marked as deprecated/superseded).

Depending on what you are up to, [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (blocking) or [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (non-blocking) may be better/simpler to use, as these send the window messages generated by input events directly.

Answer (score 0):

well, for highgui windows, try this instead:

```
void onmouse( int event, int x, int y, int d, void *ptr )
{
    // cache coords for use in main()
    cv::Point * p = (cv::Point *)ptr;
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;

    if ( event != 0 )
        cout << event << " " << x << " " << y << " "  << d << " " << endl;
}
int main() 
{

    cv::namedWindow("win",1);
    cv::Point p;
    cv::SetMouseCallback("win",onmouse,(void*)(&p));
    ...
    // whenever someone clicks or moves, the coords will be in p now
```